# Sorting columns and selecting top n rows in each group pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a dataframe like this:

```
mainid  pidx    pidy   score
  1      a        b      2
  1      a        c      5
  1      c        a      7
  1      c        b      2
  1      a        e      8
  2      x        y      1
  2      y        z      3
  2      z        y      5
  2      x        w      12
  2      x        v      1
  2      y        x      6
```

I want to `groupby` on column `'pidx'`  and then sort `score` in descending order in each group i.e for each `pidx`

and then `select head(2)` i.e top 2 from each group.

The result I am looking for is like this:

```
mainid   pidx    pidy    score
  1        a      e        8
  1        a      c        5
  1        c      a        7
  1        c      b        2
  2        x      w        12
  2        x      y        1
  2        y      x        6
  2        y      z        3
  2        z      y        5
```

What I tried was:

```py
df.sort(['pidx','score'],ascending = False).groupby('pidx').head(2)
```

and this seems to work, but I dont know if it's the right approach if working on a huge dataset. What other best method can I use to get such result?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

There are 2 solutions:

1.[`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and aggregate [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df1 = df.sort_values('score',ascending = False).groupby('pidx').head(2)
print (df1)

    mainid pidx pidy  score
8        2    x    w     12
4        1    a    e      8
2        1    c    a      7
10       2    y    x      6
1        1    a    c      5
7        2    z    y      5
6        2    y    z      3
3        1    c    b      2
5        2    x    y      1
```

2.[`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and aggregate [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['mainid','pidy']).groupby('pidx')['score'].nlargest(2).reset_index() 
print (df)
  pidx  mainid pidy  score
0    a       1    e      8
1    a       1    c      5
2    c       1    a      7
3    c       1    b      2
4    x       2    w     12
5    x       2    y      1
6    y       2    x      6
7    y       2    z      3
8    z       2    y      5
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000

L1 = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstu')
L2 = list('efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
df = pd.DataFrame({'mainid':np.random.randint(1000, size=N),
                   'pidx': np.random.randint(10000, size=N),
                   'pidy': np.random.choice(L2, N),
                   'score':np.random.randint(1000, size=N)})
#print (df)

def epat(df):
    grouped = df.groupby('pidx')
    new_df = pd.DataFrame([], columns = df.columns)
    for key, values in grouped:
        new_df = pd.concat([new_df, grouped.get_group(key).sort_values('score', ascending=True)[:2]], 0)
    return (new_df)

print (epat(df))

In [133]: %timeit (df.sort_values('score',ascending = False).groupby('pidx').head(2))
1 loop, best of 3: 309 ms per loop

In [134]: %timeit (df.set_index(['mainid','pidy']).groupby('pidx')['score'].nlargest(2).reset_index())
1 loop, best of 3: 7.11 s per loop

In [147]: %timeit (epat(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 22 s per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

a simple solution would be:

```
grouped = DF.groupby('pidx')

new_df = pd.DataFrame([], columns = DF.columns)

for key, values in grouped:

    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, grouped.get_group(key).sort_values('score', ascending=True)[:2]], 0)
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to rank scores in each group and filter the rows where the scores are ranked top 2 in each group.

```py
df1 = df[df.groupby('pidx')['score'].rank(method='first', ascending=False) <= 2]
```