# How to get the n most frequent or top values per column in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my dataframe looks like:

```
df:
    A   B
0   a   g
1   f   g
2   a   g
3   a   d
4   h   d
5   f   a
```

for top 2 most frequent values per column (n=2), the output should be:

```
top_df:
    A   B
0   a   g
1   f   d
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825978) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069009)

Comment: these give top rows, not values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
n = 2
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.value_counts().index[:n]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23197324/pandas-value-counts-applied-to-each-column) could help

```
maxes = dict()
for col in df.columns:
    frequencies = df[col].value_counts()
    # value counts automatically sorts, so just take the first 2
    max[col] = frequencies[:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**
To get the `n` most frequent values, just subset `.value_counts()` and grab the index:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# METHOD 1 : Lil lengthy and inefficient
top_dict = {}
n_freq_items = 2
top_dict['A'] = df.A.value_counts()[:n_freq_items].index.tolist()
top_dict['B'] = df.B.value_counts()[:n_freq_items].index.tolist()
top_df = pd.DataFrame(top_dict)

print(top_df)
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.value_counts()[:n_freq_items].index))

# METHOD 2 : Small, and better : taking this method from @myccha. As I found this better
top_df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.value_counts()[:n_freq_items].index))
print(top_df)
```

**INPUT DATA:**

```
# test.csv
A,B
a,g
f,g
a,g
a,d
h,d
f,a
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   A  B
0  a  g
1  f  d
```

**NOTE:** I have taken solution from **@myccha**, another answer from this post, as I found his answer more helpful, added it as METHOD 2.