# How to select top n columns from time series data instead of using nlargest in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have weekly based trade export time-series data that I need to make a stacked bar plot for visualizing trade activity. To do so, I aggregated my data for sum-up of each columns for all rows, then use `nlargest()` to select top n columns. However, doing this way might not be quite accurate because I made stacked plot for different years in the loop and top n columns for each year can be different. But what I did, take the total sum of each column for all rows (a.k.a, including all years) then select top n columns, which is biased. So, I am looking at the different way of doing this, perhaps, I might group the time series data by each year then make the stacked plot. Is there other way around selecting top n columns from time-series data instead of using `nlargest`? Does anyone know any possible way of doing this? What other way we could select top n columns from time-series data? Any idea?

**my current attempt**:

this is my current attempt to manipulate time series data, where I aggregate each columns for all rows then select top n columns using `nlargest()`:

```
import pandas as pd

# load the data
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/a6048e547b5a963c7af356c964d15af6/raw/c57c7915cf14f81edc9d5eadaf14efbd43d3e58a/trade_df.csv'
df_ = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['weekly'])
df_.set_index('weekly', inplace=True)
df_.loc['Total',:]= df_.sum(axis=0)
df1 = df_.T
df1 =df1.nlargest(6, columns=['Total'])
df1.drop('Total', axis=1, inplace=True)
df2 = df1.T
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2['weekly'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['weekly'])
df2['year'] = df2['weekly'].dt.year
df2['week'] = df2['weekly'].dt.strftime('%W').astype('int')
```

then I visualize the plotting data with `matplotlib` as follow:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt_df = df2.set_index(['year','week'])
plt_df.drop("weekly", axis=1, inplace=True)
for n, g in plt_df.groupby(level=0):
    ax = g.loc[n].plot.bar(stacked=True, title=f'{n} Year', figsize=(8,5))
    plt.show()
```

although the [output of current approach in stacked](https://ibb.co/pzPGLgx) plot is fine, but selecting top n columns using `nlargest()` is not quite accurate.for example, in 2019 USDA report, China wasn't top trade partner of US, but in late 2020, China was getting more products from US, and if I use `nlargest()` to select top column (or trade partners), it is going to be problematic and China won't be in list and not in the plot.

**update**

As @Vaishali suggested in the comment with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825978/sorting-columns-and-selecting-top-n-rows-in-each-group-pandas-dataframe), using `head()` might be good idea to extract top columns, so I tried like this:

```
for n, g in plt_df.groupby(level=0):
    for i in g:
        gg = g[i].sort_values(g[i].values,ascending = False).groupby('week').head(5)
        ax = gg.loc[n].plot.bar(stacked=True, title=f'{n} Year', figsize=(8,5))
```

but this is not working. Can anyone point me out how to select top n columns from time series data? any idea?

Comment: I think you are looking for head() instead of nlargest(). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825978/sorting-columns-and-selecting-top-n-rows-in-each-group-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @Vaishali I updated my post by using `head` that suggested in above `SO` post, but it is not working. Could you elaborate on your thoughts on how this can be solved? any thoughts?

Comment: I can't read data on my machine. If you post first few rows of the df, it will be easier for someone to look at it

Comment: @Vaishali does [this gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/a6048e547b5a963c7af356c964d15af6/raw/c57c7915cf14f81edc9d5eadaf14efbd43d3e58a/trade_df.csv) works for you? or [this link](https://filebin.net/791ihzo1dwqk3ylv/dat.csv?t=7t56bve8) to see time-series data that I used.

Comment: @Vaishali thanks a lot for your input. I am expecting list of countries for different year could be different or slightly different, so I tried something like this `df2.loc[:,(df2.groupby(level=0).sum().rank(axis=1, ascending=False)<6).any()]`. How should we do this right?

Comment: see my edit. You can filter df inside the loop to have top countries by year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/a6048e547b5a963c7af356c964d15af6/raw/c57c7915cf14f81edc9d5eadaf14efbd43d3e58a/trade_df.csv'
df_ = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['weekly'])
df_['weekly'] = pd.to_datetime(df_['weekly'])
df_.set_index('weekly', inplace=True)

for g, n in df_.groupby(df_.index.year):
    ng = n.loc[:, n.sum().rank(ascending=False, method='min')<5]
    ng.div(ng.sum(axis=1), axis=0).plot.area(title=f'{g}')
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Bar chart:

import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

```
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/a6048e547b5a963c7af356c964d15af6/raw/c57c7915cf14f81edc9d5eadaf14efbd43d3e58a/trade_df.csv'
df_ = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['weekly'])
df_['weekly'] = pd.to_datetime(df_['weekly'])
df_.set_index('weekly', inplace=True)

for g, n in df_.groupby(df_.index.year):
    ng = n.loc[:, n.sum().rank(ascending=False, method='min')<5]
    ng.index = ng.index.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    ax = ng.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(10,8))
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Staked 100% Bar chart:

```
#(previous code)
ax = ng.div(ng.sum(axis=1), axis=0).plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(10,8))
```

Output:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is quite interesting and close to my expected answer. Could we make a stacked bar plot as well?

Comment: how should we make stacked bar plot where x-axis shows 52 weeks? Any possible idea?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure I understand the requirement correctly here, but this is based on your output charts:

find top n countries using sum and nlargest
filter df by top_countries, groupby year and week, sum
for each unique year, plot stacked chart

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
top_countries = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum().nlargest(6).index.tolist()
df['weekly'] = pd.to_datetime(df['weekly'])
agg = df[top_countries].groupby([df['weekly'].dt.year.rename('year'),df['weekly'].dt.week.rename('week')]).sum()
for year in df['weekly'].dt.year.unique():
    agg[agg.index.get_level_values(0) == year].droplevel(level=0).plot.bar(stacked = True, figsize = (10,5), title = year)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Edit:
If you want to filter top countries by year, move the part where you are filtering df into the loop,

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df['weekly'] = pd.to_datetime(df['weekly'])
for year in df['weekly'].dt.year.unique():
    top_countries = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum().nlargest(6).index.tolist()
    agg = df[top_countries].groupby([df['weekly'].dt.year.rename('year'),df['weekly'].dt.week.rename('week')]).sum()

    agg[agg.index.get_level_values(0) == year].droplevel(level=0).plot.bar(stacked = True, figsize = (10,5), title = year)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
import pandas as pd

# load the data
url = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/a6048e547b5a963c7af356c964d15af6/raw/c57c7915cf14f81edc9d5eadaf14efbd43d3e58a/trade_df.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=['weekly'])
df['weekly'] = pd.to_datetime(df['weekly'])
df['year'] = df['weekly'].dt.year
df['week'] = df['weekly'].dt.strftime('%W').astype('int')
df.set_index(['year', 'week'], inplace=True)
df.drop('weekly', axis=1, inplace=True)

df_year_sums = df.groupby(level='year').sum().T

for year in df_year_sums.columns:
    largest = list(df_year_sums[year].nlargest(6).index)  
    df_plot = df.xs(year, level='year')[largest]
    df_plot.plot.bar(stacked=True, title=f'{year} Year', figsize=(8,5))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df=pd.read_csv('trade_df.csv',parse_dates=['weekly'])
 df['weekly']=pd.to_datetime(df['weekly'])
 df['Total']=0
 df.reset_index()
 for key,row in df.iterrows():
     sum=0.0
     for row_value in row:
        if type(row_value)==float:
            sum+=row_value
     df.loc[key,'Total']=sum

 results=df.sort_values(by="Total",ascending=False)

 print(results.head(5))   


 #grouped=df.groupby('year').sum().T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
 #plt.show() 

 filter=df['year'].isin([2018])
 results_2018=df[filter].sort_values(by=['total'],ascending=False).head(5)

 filter=df['year'].isin([2019])
 results_2019=df[filter].sort_values(by=['total'],ascending=False).head(5)

 filter=df['year'].isin([2020])
 results_2020=df[filter].sort_values(by=['total'],ascending=False).head(5)

 grouped=df.groupby('year').sum().T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
 plt.show()

 fp=results_2018.pivot_table(index=['week'],aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
 fp = fp[(fp.T != 0).any()]

 fp2=results_2019.pivot_table(index=['week'],aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
 fp2 = fp2[(fp2.T != 0).any()]

 fp3=results_2020.pivot_table(index=['week'],aggfunc='sum').fillna(0)
 fp3 = fp3[(fp3.T != 0).any()]

 #print(fp)
 fig,ax=plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(16,16))
 fp.plot.bar(stacked=True,ax=ax[0])
 fp2.plot.bar(stacked=True,ax=ax[1])
 fp3.plot.bar(stacked=True,ax=ax[2])
 plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,(100)),columns=["column1"])
results=np.array(df.sort_values(by="column1",ascending=False)).flatten()
print(results[:5])
```

Comment: could you try time series data for this, like the one in my attempt? I think this is not what I expected. Any possible update? Thanks

Comment: what field are your sorting on? what field is being aggregated summed?

Comment: I think we add new filed called "total", but not sure how your given attempt works for time series data that I used. Do you mind to try [time series data that I used](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/adamFlyn/a6048e547b5a963c7af356c964d15af6/raw/c57c7915cf14f81edc9d5eadaf14efbd43d3e58a/trade_df.csv) in your attempt? Thanks!